# Page loading is failed when visiting for 1st time but works fine when visited later on

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I get status as cancelled when I open the page for the first time and the page is stuck on loading screen because I get the status as **Canceled** , but when I open the same page after again it opens. Upon looking at the Network time I noticed the cancelled status and the Initiator was **jquery.min.js**. I think there must be an issue related to **jquery.min.js**, but I can't find a confident solution to solve this problem. Or is any library missing?
My project is in ASP.Net and Jquery is used in the `.cshtml` files.
[image: here you can see the canceled status]
[image]

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>
        @{
            // set custom page title from global configuration
            string title = MultiLanguageFactory.TranslateText(ARMCommon.GetGlobalConfigStringValue(ARMCommon.GLOBAL_CONFIG_CUSTOM_PAGE_TITLE));
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            {
                title = MultiLanguageFactory.TranslateText(ARMCommon.DEFAULT_PAGE_TITLE);
            }
        }
        @title
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        Cour = {
            WebRoot: '@Url.Content("~/")',
            ApiRoot: '@Url.Content("~/api/")',
            Culture: '@HttpContext.Current.Session["lang"].ToString()'
        };
    </script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/less/kendo/kendo.common.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/less/kendo/kendo.default.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/styles/mvc")
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/less/WebFonts.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/less/Access.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("GetResources", "Mlf", new { area = "" })"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/common")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.2.716/cultures/kendo.culture." + HttpContext.Current.Session["lang"] + ".min.js")"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/html5shiv.js")"></script>
      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/respond.min.js")"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        kendo.culture('@HttpContext.Current.Session["lang"]');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ConvertDateColumnsToCurrentCulture.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Date.js")"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
        In IE8, sometimes the web fonts would not render, despite being
        downloaded. This function tricks IE8 into re-rendering the body
        by adding a dummy class after the onload event has been triggered.
        If icons continue to not load, the timeout length may need to
        be increased.

        This function is present in:
        PortalMaster-CRCC-Bootstrap.master
        PortalMaster-Bootstrap.master
        _Layout_Bootstrap.cshtml

        The function is called in the body onload event.

        function iconFix() {
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8) {
                setTimeout(function () { $(document.body).addClass("dummy"); }, 800);
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body id="@Html.GenerateBodyId()" onload="iconFix()">
    @Html.Partial("_MegaMenu_Bootstrap")
    <div id="page-title">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>@Html.TranslateText(PageTitle)</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    
    @* If a Courion Session is active, include the scripts for the session timeout dialog *@
    @if (Courion.Aspx.Portal.SessionManagement.CourAspxSession.IsCourSessionActive())
    {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/session")
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {
                if (settings.func != "noReset") {
                    //This is to keep session alive
                    Ext.Courion.AspxTimeoutManager.resetTimeout();
                }
            });
        </script>
    }
    @RenderSection("JavaScript", false)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Deprecated. Placeholder is now an attribute.
            //$('input, textarea').placeholder();
            $('input, textarea').attr("placeholder");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you move the @RenderSection("JavaScript", false) above the Courion Session block?

Comment: @G_P nothing happened. no changes, still having the same issue..